VCVARSALL.BAT for Visual studio 2022 is not set INCLUDE for windows sdk 8.1
I run vcvars32 as:
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat" 8.1
And when
set INCLUDE
output:
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd\core>set INCL
INCLUDE=c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include;c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\ATLMFC\include;c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um

c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd\core>

So if I try like #include <windows.h> then I have an compilation error:
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
File windows.h exists:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\windows.h
in the registry sdk 8.1 is registered, vсvars even sets other envariment variables like:
D:\>set Windo
WindowsLibPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral
WindowsSdkBinPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\
WindowsSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\
WindowsSDKLibVersion=winv6.3\
WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\
WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x86=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\

D:\>

This SDK (8.1) I see as installed in the VS2017 installer. And running vcvars32.bat 8.1 for VS2017 works good. All paths are correct and compilation is successfull. I even try to install Win 8.1 SDK from separate installer.
In the MS docs I see that "8.1" is still correct parameter for vcvarsall and can be used.
Tested on 3 different PC. This problem exists on all of them. Any ideas how to fix it?
